# I need to reverse the order of my ORDER BY results

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I need to get 3 rows with the lowest value in a certain column, and then reverse the order of these 3 rows.  So if the 3 rows with the lowest value are A, B and C, I need to sort them as C, B and A.  Could I do that in a single SQL statement?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ratings_table ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 3";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck > 0) 
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        echo "<td>".$row['rating']."</td>";
    }
}
```

With this code I will get the right results but in the wrong order.

Comment: `ORDER BY ... DESC`?

Comment: ORDER BY v DESC...

Comment: Need to see your query.

Comment: you can sort by multiple columns in either order: 
ex: 
SELECT Id, CompanyName, City, Country
  FROM Supplier
 WHERE Country IN ('USA', 'Japan', 'Germany')
 ORDER BY Country ASC, CompanyName DESC

Comment: I posted my query.  It gives me the right results, but the wrong order.

Comment: If you want to get the lowest 3 but order them in descending order, you'll need to use a subquery

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: I'm using MySQLi.  How do I use a subquery?  Should I look it up or could you post what I should write =)

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to use a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
   (
     SELECT * 
     FROM ratings_table 
     ORDER BY rating ASC LIMIT 3
   ) a 
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

This will take the lowest three results , then flop the order.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't change the order of my results!  I even tried appending ASC and DESC to the end but no difference.

Comment: Oh my bad this does work, I made a mistake.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Only a sub-query will work. First you select the 3 lowest values and then sort them.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT <COLUMN_VALUE>
        FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
    ORDER BY <COLUMN_VALUE> LIMIT 3
) T
ORDER BY <COLUMN_VALUE> DESC
```

Comment: Don't add duplicate answer if you have another approach please update your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ratings_table ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 3";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)->fetch_all();
krsort($result)
foreach ($result as $row) 
{
    echo "<td>".$row['rating']."</td>";
}
```